# Application Insights trace log to OMS Log Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

We have Application Insights connector configured with OMS Log Analytics. We are seeing only CustomEvents & Exceptions Telemetry Type in OMS Log Analytics and I dont see Trace Telemetry type in OMS Log Analytics. Whether Trace is CustomEvent in OMS Log Analytics or Traces are not available in OMS Log Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

Not all of the Application Insights data types are sent through the connector to Log Analytics. Traces are one of the data types that aren’t supported in Log Analytics, so you won't be able to see it in OMS at all

Comment: EranG - do you have a source for that info?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like OMS's AI connector can only see,  Custom Events, Requests, PageViews, Availability and Exceptions..

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-app-insights-connector#input-data

I'm having same issue,  want to be able to se ALL the AI data in OMS..  Would loved to be proved wrong here..